# Charge outside a Sphere given charge density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

If a sphere has a charge density of  $\rho =\alpha  r^2$, I want to calculate the Electric field outside of the sphere.

Starting with Maxwell's equation $\bigtriangledown\cdot E=\frac{\rho }{\epsilon _o}$ and using the divergence theorem we get Gauss'law: $\int _V \bigtriangledown\cdot \overset{\rightharpoonup }{E}~d^3x=\int _S \overset{\rightharpoonup }{E}\cdot \hat{n} ~~da=\frac{1}{\epsilon _o}\int _V\rho ( \overset{\rightharpoonup }{x})d^3x$

Which I solve as: $E~ 4 \pi  r^2=\frac{4 \pi }{\epsilon _o} \int_0^R \alpha ~r^4 \, dr$ = $\frac{4 ~\pi~\alpha~ R^5}{5~\epsilon _o}~\\$

Giving a final answer of: $E = \frac{\alpha ~R^5}{5~ r^2 ~\epsilon _o}$

However, I found a similar problem online and it had the same answer with $\frac{1}{3}$ instead of $\frac{1}{5}$ - they didn't' integrate over the charge density but simply assumed: $Q_{\text{enc}}=\rho  V=\left(\alpha  R^2\right)\frac{4 \pi  R^3}{3} $ which leads to the solution $E= \frac{\alpha ~R^5}{3~ r^2 ~\epsilon _o}$. I'm not sure now which one is correct physically?

Secondly, I don't know how to track the vector diretion of $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{E}$ in the final answer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach using Gauss and the integration to find the total charge is correct.  The method which just multiplies the charge density as though it was constant (independent of R) by the volume of a sphere is incorrect.

The E-field lines will be radial and be in the outward direction if the charge is positive.